# TypeScript - Group objects by keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following object:

```
const original = [{
        "key-8": {
            "some object"
        }
    },
    {
        "key-12": {
            "some object"
        }
    },
    {
        "key-12": {
            "some object"
        }
    },
    {
        "key-1": {
            "some object"
        }
    },
    {
        "key-8": {
            "some object"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see I have two objects with `key-8` and two with `key-12`.
I would like to combine them (the order does not matter) so the output will be:

```
{
    {
        "key-12": [{
                "some object"
            },
            {
                "some object"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "key-1": {
            {
                "some object"
            }
        },
        {
            "key-8": [{
                    "some object"
                },
                {
                    "some object"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot make it works no matter what I try. I used `reduce`, I used regular `forEach` and other "hacks" simple do not work because TypeScript does not like them.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: @IISkullsII tried this, it does not work for me. probably i am doing something wrong :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you've got `"..."` everywhere?  It makes it hard to tell the difference between correct output and incorrect output (what if I just copy the first object over and over again)?  Could you make this more of a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz agree, done

Comment: Now you still have identical things, except they are no longer valid TS or JS (`{"some object"}` is a syntax error).  I was saying you should make them have different contents so you could actually distinguish correct from incorrect output.

Comment: Please fix the input/output so that it is valid JS.  You can't have `{ {}, {} }` and you can't have `{""}` as objects.  Also, do you *really* want the output to be an array-of-dictionaries-of-objects-or-arrays-of-objects? Like, if I fix your syntax errors and add distinguishing data then [this approach](//tsplay.dev/WkK30W) gives that output, but I'd think you'd rather have a single dictionary of arrays of objects like [this](//tsplay.dev/WvAQAm), which is simpler to implement and simpler to process.  I'm happy to write either of those as an answer but only if the question is improved first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const orig = [
  {
    "key-8": {
      "key": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "info": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "key-12": {
      "key": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "info": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "key-12": {
      "key": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "info": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "key-1": {
      "key": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "info": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "key-8": {
      "key": "...",
      "value": "...",
      "info": "..."
    }
  }
];


const result = orig.reduce(function (r, a) {
    const { key, ...others } = Object.values(a)[0];
    r[Object.keys(a)] = r[Object.keys(a)] || [];
    r[Object.keys(a)].push(others);
    return r;
  }, Object.create(null));

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: it works but i produces a wrong structure. the keys are repeated inside and i do not want them there

Comment: @kolomichenko destructuring your object (a) like this: const { key, ...others } = a; and push(others) instead push(a)

Comment: this one also produces unexpected result